# How to clone an option from a select to another one at a time?

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

Good day. I am trying to copy/clone an option one at a time from one select to another. However, all SO that I found clones everything. Hope that you can help me with my concern.

What I do know:

html:

```
<select name="languages" id="id_languages" class="languages-select">
  <option value="EN">ENGLISH</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var lang = document.getElementById("id_languages");
console.log(lang)
```

value of `lang` is the whole select. I want the `option` so that I can append it to another select multiple.

Answer (score 0):

sorry. I just got it.

```
lang.options[lang.selectedIndex]
```